# How to disable nesting of triggers at table or trigger level in SQLServer?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, database-trigger, ssms-2012

Using SQL Server 2012, is it possible to have nested triggers enabled at the server/database level but to disable nesting on one specific table/trigger?

Comment: IMO, nested triggers are usually the wrong design. Hard (practically impossible) to debug, hard to maintain. Do you have an XY problem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think that you should be able to achieve your purpose by using [the `TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL()` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/trigger-nestlevel-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2012), which is available since SQL Server 2008:

> Returns the number of triggers executed for the statement that fired the trigger. `TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL` is used in DML and DDL triggers to determine the current level of nesting.

You could alter the code of the relevant trigger to add the following statement just after the `BEGIN` keyword. The trick is to dynamically compute the `object_id` of the current trigger, which `TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL()` expects as first argument:

```
IF TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL(
    ( SELECT object_id FROM sys.triggers WHERE name = 'MyTrigger' )
) > 1 RETURN
```

This will actually prevent the given trigger to execute recursively.

Another option is to use `TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL()` without arguments. This returns the number of times all triggers have been executed for the statement. My understanding of your use case is that the first solution should be what you need.

Comment: Indeed, this works, is an elegant solution and even allows to control the depth of nested triggering if it's required.

Comment: @SebastianZartner: indeed... See [this post](https://www.google.fr/amp/s/clivesyabb.com/2014/08/06/avoiding-recursive-triggers-in-sql-vs-avoiding-nested-execution/amp/) for a full testing scenario.

Comment: More concise expression for the ID would be `OBJECT_ID('my_trigger', 'TR' )`

Comment: The best statement would IMHO be `TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL(@@PROCID)`. No need to call any other function.